# Extra Text in URL

Tags: redirect, homepage, home-url

I'm redesigning my website.  The blog posts and everything were fairly easy to move to the new wordpress install.

The URL of the test site is this: http://www.NathanTornquist.com/wordpress

When I go to that URL I have this URL show up in the address bar: http://www.NathanTornquist.com/NathanTornquist/wordpress

but when I hit the home button at any time the site goes to NathanTornquist.com/wordpress as it should.  What do I need to do to correct this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra "nathantornquist" in the URL happens when you don't have the trailing slash on `http://www.nathantornquist.com/wordpress`. What are the contents of your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

In WordPress Admin Dashboard go to -> Settings and check out if WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are correct (http://nathantornquist.com/wordpress/)

Then, if everything is correct there, go to CPanel, and check out if there is any domain redirection set up in place, and delete it.

If you still don't have luck, using CPanel/FTP manager delete .htaccess file from the root of your domain.

Come back with results ;)